# JIRA Usage on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, url, jira

I just set up JIRA on my ec2 instance after installing it via .bin installer file. But when I hit the ec2 url:

ec2-xxxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com

It is hitting the test success page for apache2 which I installed after JIRA installation.

How do I get to determine the correct URL for JIRA and hit the JIRA app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default JIRA is running on port 8080. So you have to type the port after your URL and open the ports in your security groups (Firewall).

```
http://ec2-xxxxx.xxxxx.amazonaws.com:8080
```

If you want JIRA under a specific domain you have to install a proxy to redirect it from port 80 to 8080.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Integrating+JIRA+with+nginx
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+Apache

Comment: Thanks @Stony I did hit the 8080 port, but it is saying that webpage is not available. Has it anything to do with ec2 security group config? Do I need to add a rule to allow TCP on 8080?

Comment: Yes you have to add the port to it.

Comment: Yep that did it! Accepting your answer. For the records a custom TCP rule allowing TCP connexions on 8080 has to be added for the ec2 security group...